# Displaying images in Sencha Touch given digest

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, couchdb, pouchdb

My goal is to display an image in Sencha Touch 2.

As of now, I'm doing something like this:

```
{
    xtype:'image',
    src: 'resources/icons/default_avatar.png',
    height: 256,
    width: 256
}
```

In the future, I want to get those images from the database.

In PouchDB, this looks like:

```
"avatar.png": {
      "content_type": "image/png",
      "digest": "md5-ewjS8WP/imog6RFh07xqHg==", <-- altered
      "length": 10741,
      "data": "abe24==" <-- made this up; too long to paste
    }
```

I am trying to accomplish the following:

Say there are 2 buttons (ids: ['b1', 'b2']. When I click on one, I get taken to another page and see the image that corresponds with the clicked button.

I look up 'b1' in the database and find the base64 image. How can I display that? It looks like the "src" property is only for urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [blob-util](https://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util) to convert the attachments stored in PouchDB into usable `<img/>` tags.

[db.getAttachment()](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#get_attachment) will give you back the Blob, then use [createObjectURL](https://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util#createObjectURL) to convert the blob into a URL you can use.

Sure, you can also use base64 strings and convert it to a data URL (blob-util offers this functionality as well), but it is far less efficient than working directly with Blobs.

Comment: If I'm already making a `get()` call above, should i just "include_attachments:true" and take the base64 penalty, rather than making an additional call?

Comment: In the next release of PouchDB (3.7.0 probably), you'll be able to do `get()` with `{include_docs: true, binary: true}` and get back the blob. For now, it's probably more efficient to do the extra request, rather than go with base64.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can still use `src` -- but you'll have to prepend the base64 bits with the proper `data:image/png;base64,` bit.

```
{
    xtype : 'image',
    src  : 'data:image/png;base64,' + record.data
}
```

You could also simply create a generic component and shove some raw HTML (with your [base64 image code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)) into its `html` config.

Something like:

```
{
    xtype : 'component',
    html  : '<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,' + record.data + '" />'
}
```